# Accidentally deleted the content of apache2/logs/wsgi.x.x.sock now getting Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process in log

Tags: apache, apache2

I accidentally deleted the content of apache2/logs on my webserver.
The folder containeed two files a pid file and a sock file now I am getting the error

```
Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'xxxx' on '/home/admin/webapps/myapp/apache2/logs/wsgi.18851.161.1.sock' as user with uid=1122.
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this. I think I need to change the sock filename to the new file which was  created when I restarted the apache server. The new file is `wsgi.4397.1.1.sock`now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just restart Apache. It will recreate it and it should be good. The name of the socket file will change with each restart as it includes the process ID of the Apache root process.

Although, if you deleted the whole logs directory, you will need to make sure you create the directory again with correct owner and permissions as was before. Don't do that and the user that Apache runs as may not be able to see inside of the directory to connect to the socket.

Comment: I did not delete the directory just the content. Apart from that why in the log is it trying to access the old sock file ?

Comment: Did you do a reload or a restart? To be safe use restart (not reload), or even do stop and then start. Even on a reload it should use a different filename for socket as the second or third number is the Apache generation, corresponding to how many times a reload has been done.

Comment: Also, you can get connect errors if you do a reload and you had keep alive connections in progress which stopped the Apache child processes from being restarted promptly. They will use stale information about the name of the socket. Not possible to do anything about it because of how Apache manages the daemon processes. They will occur whilst the keep alive connections keep the process active. Once it finally is killed, should be okay again.

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that . Infact I removed all the logs in `/home/admin/logs/user` just so I dont get confused by other log files. So now I am still getting the 503 service unavailable error only not that message in the log file

Comment: Seems like sometimes the page loads and sometimes it doesnt. Funny behaviour

Comment: So what is the message in the Apache error logs now?

Comment: When are no error messages in error_appname.log. Whenever there is a 503 service unavailable nothing is in the log file. Is that normal ?

Comment: Filename ``error_appname.log`` is a strange name for an Apache error log. Is that really an Apache error log file, or are you logging from a Python web application using ``logging`` module. For Apache error logs, make sure you are checking both the virtual host log if one, or main Apache error log. If there is a 503 coming from Apache, it should log something. It is unusual for a Python web application itself to return a 503.